# Next js app does not render on chrome properly

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, rendering, tailwind-css

I am using nextjs & tailwind css in my app and it is breaking on chrome. I don't know why it is happening.

Images are not being loaded properly & once They load, they disappear then.
I am using nextjs `Image` tag for rendering images.
Here is the way I'm using to render images:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
const Tech = ({ icon, text }) => (
  <div className='flex flex-col justify-between gap-2 bg-[rgba(21,21,21,0.15)] px-2.5   py-4'>
    <Image src={icon} alt={text} />
    <p className='text-sm leading-4'>{text}</p>
  </div>
);

export default Tech;
```

You can check it [here](https://dev.datumbrain.com/)

Here are some snapshots attached:
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

It is perfectly working on Firefox btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the `backdrop-filter` CSS property as it is very UI expensive. I replaced it with opacity.